# How can I add style to the active tab in sidenav using state

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I am making a side nav for which I need to add the left border to the current tab How can I achieve this using state by passing a boolean value to the Child SideNavItem class as a prop and the change it on every tab change.

**Here is My code for the parent SideNav class**
Here I am using an if-else condition to check for the current location and the pass that is a prop to the Child class. But Right now both the Home and My Profile is getting the side border.

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import SideNavItems from "./SideNavItems";
import React, {useState} from 'react';


const HomeIcon = (
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    className="h-8 w-6"
    fill="none"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    stroke="currentColor"
  >
    <path
      strokeLinecap="round"
      strokeLinejoin="round"
      strokeWidth={2}
      d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7 7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6"
    />
  </svg>
);
const ProfileIcon = (
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    className="h-8 w-6"
    fill="none"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    stroke="currentColor"
  >
    <path
      strokeLinecap="round"
      strokeLinejoin="round"
      strokeWidth={2}
      d="M16 7a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0zM12 14a7 7 0 00-7 7h14a7 7 0 00-7-7z"
    />
  </svg>
);
const PointIcon = (
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    className="h-8 w-6"
    fill="none"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    stroke="currentColor"
  >
    <path
      strokeLinecap="round"
      strokeLinejoin="round"
      strokeWidth={2}
      d="M11.049 2.927c.3-.921 1.603-.921 1.902 0l1.519 4.674a1 1 0 00.95.69h4.915c.969 0 1.371 1.24.588 1.81l-3.976 2.888a1 1 0 00-.363 1.118l1.518 4.674c.3.922-.755 1.688-1.538 1.118l-3.976-2.888a1 1 0 00-1.176 0l-3.976 2.888c-.783.57-1.838-.197-1.538-1.118l1.518-4.674a1 1 0 00-.363-1.118l-3.976-2.888c-.784-.57-.38-1.81.588-1.81h4.914a1 1 0 00.951-.69l1.519-4.674z"
    />
  </svg>
);
const SupportIcon = (
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    className="h-8 w-6"
    fill="none"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    stroke="currentColor"
  >
    <path
      strokeLinecap="round"
      strokeLinejoin="round"
      strokeWidth={2}
      d="M4.318 6.318a4.5 4.5 0 000 6.364L12 20.364l7.682-7.682a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364-6.364L12 7.636l-1.318-1.318a4.5 4.5 0 00-6.364 0z"
    />
  </svg>
);
const ContributeIcon = (
  <svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    className="h-8 w-6"
    fill="none"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    stroke="currentColor"
  >
    <path
      strokeLinecap="round"
      strokeLinejoin="round"
      strokeWidth={2}
      d="M10 20l4-16m4 4l4 4-4 4M6 16l-4-4 4-4"
    />
  </svg>
);




const SideNav = (): JSX.Element => {
  let [active, setActive] = useState(true);
  let isActive = (currentPath: any, thisPath: any) => {
    if (currentPath===thisPath) {
      setActive(true)
    } else {
      setActive(false);
    }
    return active;
  }
  const resetState = () => {
    setActive(false);
  };
  return (
    <div className="sidebar mt-5">
      <div className="logo ml-2">
        <img
            alt="logo"
            src={require("../assets/images/logo.png").default}
          />
      </div>
        <NavLink to="/"><SideNavItems active={() => isActive(window.location.pathname, "/")} icon={HomeIcon} text={"Home"}/></NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/profile"><SideNavItems active={() => isActive(window.location.pathname, "/profile")} icon={ProfileIcon} text={"My Profile"}/></NavLink>
        <SideNavItems active={""} icon={PointIcon} text={"Daily Points"}/>
        <SideNavItems active={""} icon={SupportIcon} text={"Support"}/>
        <SideNavItems active={""} icon={ContributeIcon} text={"Contribute"}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SideNav;
```

**Here is the code for Child Class**

```
import React from "react";

type Props = {
  active: any;
  text: string;
  icon: any;
};
const SideNavItems: React.FC<Props> = ({active, icon, text }) => (
  <div className={`flex items-center cursor-pointer hover:text-red-400 transition duration-100 ease-in-out ${active ? ` text-red-400 border-l-4 border-red-400` : ``}`}>
    <div className="icon p-5">{icon}</div>
    <h2 className="font-extrabold text-xl mr-5">{text}</h2>
  </div>
);

export default SideNavItems;
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of the confusion you're facing here is due to the fact that calling `setActive` in the `isActive` function doesn't immediately change the value of the `active` variable, and since you are returning the `active` variable immediately, you are actually returning the previous value `active`, not the intended value.

In fact, you probably don't need to save the value of `active` in a component state variable:

```
const SideNav = (): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div className='sidebar mt-5'>
      <div className='logo ml-2'>
        <img alt='logo' src={require('../assets/images/logo.png').default} />
      </div>
      <NavLink to='/'>
        <SideNavItems
          active={window.location.pathname === '/'}
          icon={HomeIcon}
          text={'Home'}
        />
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to='/profile'>
        <SideNavItems
          active={window.location.pathname === '/profile'}
          icon={ProfileIcon}
          text={'My Profile'}
        />
      </NavLink>
      <SideNavItems active={''} icon={PointIcon} text={'Daily Points'} />
      <SideNavItems active={''} icon={SupportIcon} text={'Support'} />
      <SideNavItems active={''} icon={ContributeIcon} text={'Contribute'} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SideNav;
```

or if you're using react router, you can use the `useLocation` hook to make sure the component always re-renders when the path changes:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const SideNav = (): JSX.Element => {

  const { pathname: currentPath } = useLocation();

  return (
    <div className='sidebar mt-5'>
      <div className='logo ml-2'>
        <img alt='logo' src={require('../assets/images/logo.png').default} />
      </div>
      <NavLink to='/'>
        <SideNavItems
          active={currentPath === '/'}
          icon={HomeIcon}
          text={'Home'}
        />
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink to='/profile'>
        <SideNavItems
          active={currentPath === '/profile'}
          icon={ProfileIcon}
          text={'My Profile'}
        />
      </NavLink>
      <SideNavItems active={''} icon={PointIcon} text={'Daily Points'} />
      <SideNavItems active={''} icon={SupportIcon} text={'Support'} />
      <SideNavItems active={''} icon={ContributeIcon} text={'Contribute'} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SideNav;
```